# R - barplot with y-scale to see small values using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, scaletransform

I need a barplot showing a bar for every value (even if the value is something as 0.0002).  It is also important to keep the ylim to compare with other similar barplots.  Scaling the ylim is allowed but keeping the sign is important.  Any help will be really appreciated.

```
data <- c(
0.0224544949, 0.040071356,  0.005862310,
-0.0024304989, 0.025612782,  0.004551214,
-0.0021313240, 0.026042635,  0.004003015,
-0.0070571818, 0.001242457, -0.006225233,
0.0001473911, 0.052633570,  0.039935131)

bias <- matrix(data,5,3, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(bias) <- c("H=0.55","H=0.75","H=0.95")
rownames(bias) <- c("M1","M2","M3","M4","M5")

dat1 <- data.frame(
Method = factor(c("M1","M2","M3","M4","M5")),
H = factor(c(rep(c("H=0.55"),5),rep(c("H=0.75"),5),rep(c("H=0.95"),5)  ), levels=c("H=0.55","H=0.75","H=0.95")),
Bias = c(bias[,1],bias[,2],bias[,3])
)


name <- paste("Parameter bias")

ggplot(data=dat1, aes(x=H, y=Bias, fill=Method)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
        ggtitle(name) +     
        theme_bw() +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.03,0.03))
```

Comment: It's already plotting everything. If you need to keep your scales, all you can really do is make your plot really tall. If you can ditch your scales and just go by labels, facetting can help: `ggplot(data=dat1, aes(x=H, y=Bias, fill=Method)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
    ggtitle(name) +     
    theme_bw() + facet_wrap(~ H, scales = 'free')`

Comment: Are you sure you want the `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.03,0.03)) ` in there? Its causing you to lose some information. Some of the bars get cut out because they are greater than the ylim max. See `M5, H=0.75`

Answer (score 0):

If you are really concerned about small values not appearing, you could do something like tack on some horizontal error bars with `geom_errorbarh()`.

Here is an example:

```
#Slightly updated data, made M5, H=0.55 even smaller so that it doesnt appear in normal plot
data <- c(
  0.0224544949, 0.040071356,  0.005862310,
  -0.0024304989, 0.025612782,  0.004551214,
  -0.0021313240, 0.026042635,  0.004003015,
  -0.0070571818, 0.001242457, -0.006225233,
  0.00001473911, 0.052633570,  0.039935131)

bias <- matrix(data,5,3, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(bias) <- c("H=0.55","H=0.75","H=0.95")
rownames(bias) <- c("M1","M2","M3","M4","M5")

dat1 <- data.frame(
  Method = factor(c("M1","M2","M3","M4","M5")),
  H = factor(c(rep(c("H=0.55"),5),rep(c("H=0.75"),5),rep(c("H=0.95"),5)  ), levels=c("H=0.55","H=0.75","H=0.95")),
  Bias = c(bias[,1],bias[,2],bias[,3])
)
```

Your current method will give this:

```
ggplot(data=dat1, aes(x=H, y=Bias, fill=Method)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(width=0.9),width=0.9) +
  ggtitle(name) +     
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

In the above you can clearly see that `H=0.55, M5` doesn't appear since its so small. However, its still being plotted.

Now with adding error bars we can make it a tiny sliver so that we know its being plotted.

```
ggplot(data=dat1, aes(x=H, y=Bias, fill=Method)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(width=0.9),width=0.9) +
  ggtitle(name) +     
  theme_bw()+ geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax=as.numeric(H)+0.45,xmin=as.numeric(H)-0.45,height=0,color=Method),position=position_dodge(width=0.9))
```

Which gives:

[image]

Note: I took out your `ylim` code because it was cutting off some data. It would be easy enough to just tack it onto the above code with a `+scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.03,0.03))`

Comment: Thanks Mike, this seems to work.  Do you know if there is a way to make a zoom in the y axis for the interval, say (-0.01,0.01)?  I am looking for something as using log scale (with positive small values) that zooms out the small values (negatives and positives).

Comment: You want a second plot that zooms in on the small values only?

Comment: For all values (small and not) I want to zoom out the region in the y axis in the interval (-0.01,0.01) and keeping the y axis in the interval (-0.05,0.05)